# why does the Label text not change after I assigned it the value?

Tags: python, kivy

Here is a part of my code - the python file creates the buttons with the text. Then, when one of the buttons is pressed - the screen is changed and the label on the new screen must be the same as the text of the button that pressed. However the text of the label does not change even though everything else is working and there is no mistake given.

PYTHON:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        btn = Button(text = "word is here", on_release =self.pressedFunction)
        self.ids.container.add_widget(btn)

        btn1 = Button(text = "another word is here", on_release    =self.pressedFunction)
        self.ids.container.add_widget(btn1)

    def pressedFunction(self, instance, *args):
        self.manager.current= "three"

        screenThree = ScreenThree()
        text = str(instance.text)

        screenThree.changing_label(text)

class ScreenThree(Screen):
    def changing_label(self, text):
        self.ids.my_label.text = text

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("example.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
   MainApp().run()
```

KIVY:

```
ScreenManagement:
    ScreenOne:
    ScreenTwo:
    ScreenThree:

<ScreenOne>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "press me"
            on_release: app.root.current = "two"

<ScreenTwo>:    
    name: "two"

    BoxLayout:
        id: container


<ScreenThree>:
    name: "three"

    BoxLayout:
        id: labelContainer

        Label:
            text: ""
            id: my_label
```

Comment: review the [tour], read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not providing any kind of error, i'm gonna guess what could be wrong.
First of all:

```
if spawned_List[0] == "False":
```

spawned_List is not defined in your code, and i'm not sure why you would compare that object with a string "False".

```
for x in range(0,len(languages)):
```

I suggest you to do this instead:

```
for word in languages:
    btn = Button(
        text=str(word), size_hint=(None, None), size=(140,70),
        font_size=18, bold=True, color=[0,1,1,1],
        background_color=(.156, .172, .24, 0.7),
        on_release=self.changing_screen
    )
```

Another guess i could make:

```
screenSlider = SliderScreen()
```

Does not make sense if you already have an instance of it, you should use the main one instead.

And if you could provide us more about, we could maybe answer your question easily.

-----------EDIT----------------

```
screenThree = ScreenThree()
```

You're creating a new instance of ScreenThree that is not the one you expect to work, so you have two different instances of the same Class, that's why it is not working. Instead you should get that instance using the ScreenManager, or where ever you instanciated it and call the method you want.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain this right. I have now changed the code so that it looks easier and there is not irrelevant staff. Please could you have a look again so that you can understand the problem fully?